# How to make a simple login form using FormsAuthentication and MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, forms-authentication

I've tried searching how to accomplish this, but everything I can find seems too complicated and comprehensive that I can't really grasp how it works. The following is my situation:

I've got a simple **MySQL** table called `users` with three attributes: `user_id`, `username` and `password`.

In **ASP.NET** page I've got two textboxes and a login-button.

I've read that I could use `FormsAuthentication`, but I haven't been able to figure out how it works. Do I have to use "*Membership*"? Or can I use FormsAuthentication without that? I would prefer just to have it as simple as possible.

So far, I simply make a select like this:

```
        String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @UserName
           AND password = @Password;";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
```

In my code-behind I have this:

```
        String username = txtUsername.Text;
        String password = txtPassword.Text;

        User user = database.LogIn(username, password);
```

And finally in my web.config file I have this:

```
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="MyCookieName"
               loginUrl="~/Default.aspx"
               timeout="10"
               protection="All"
               path="/">
        </forms>
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
```

So far I can validate whether or not the user has entered valid input, but I don't understand how I can apply the FormsAuthentication. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Forms Authentication is not the same as Membership.
[Explanation](http://brockallen.com/2012/06/04/membership-is-not-the-same-as-forms-authentication)

You have everything set up correctly. Web.config is where you enable the Forms Auth, which is essentially an HTTP Module that checks for ASPXAUTH cookie.  In order to initially set the cookie in your code after validating the password use:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, createPersistentCookie);
```

I think this is in `System.Web.dll`, `System.Web.Security` namespace.

Your subsequent requests will have userName you specify.

Keep in mind that storing passwords in plain text is a bad idea.  Use hashing.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210519002041/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082703-1.aspx)

Ignore what they say about stored procedures. Then checkout this code

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection conn;

    if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        try 
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection("server=Cheese;user id=george; password=blah; database=mysql; pooling=false");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = 
               "SELECT G.Name  FROM Roles R INNER JOIN Groups G ON R.GroupID = G.GroupID INNER JOIN Users U ON  R.UserID = U.UserID AND U.Username = ?";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("UserName",User.Identity.Name);
            conn.Open()
            MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ArrayList groups = new ArrayList();

            while(r.Read())
                {
                    groups.Add(r.GetString(0));
            }

            HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, groups.ToArray(typeof(System.String)));
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if any query remains.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
string username,password;
if(username=="mohammadreza"&password=="12345")
{
    messageox.show("welcome");
    form1.activeform.enable=true;
}
```